# Jquery getJSON php array to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, getjson

I am testing the getJSON with php array, but it is not working, can anyone check for me ? I feel the problem is from the php code because when i test the html code with getJSON url https://graph.facebook.com/zombies, it is working.

In my array.php

```
<?php

 header("Content-type: text/javascript");

 $arr = array(

            "name" => "Tim",
            "age" => "28"     );

echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

In my test.html :

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {
         $.getJSON('array.php', function(data) {        
            if(data) {
            document.write(data.age);       
            }
            else {
            alert('error');
            }
        });
    }); 
    </script>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Try the content type application/json

Comment: ok i have solve my problem, 

in php : echo $_GET["callback"] . "(" . json_encode($arr) . ")";

in html : $.getJSON('array.php?callback=?', function(data) 

so the cross server can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `header("Content-type: text/javascript");`

You're telling the browser you're sending it JavaScript, when what you're sending it is JSON. The content type for JSON is `application/json`.

If you fix that, it should work, provided you're not running afoul of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). If you're making a cross-domain request, your options are:

- Don't use ajax and JSON, use [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP).
- Use [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/), but it requires that the server allow your document's origin, and that the browser supports it (most modern ones do, older ones don't).
- Use [YQL as a cross-domain proxy](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax).

Comment: oh ... i found my problem, because my script is inside Ubuntu server and i running it from win 7, thx for it !

Comment: i have a question, if the array transfer happen in local and cross domain, what should i do ?

Comment: @jc_tan: The cross-domain options work for the same domain as well.

Answer (score 3):

Change

`header("Content-type: text/javascript");`

To

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

For JSONP

```
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the content type to

```
application/json
```

So jQuery will interpte as json data